# Why is my sound script interfering with my advertises

Tags: android, audio, unity-game-engine, admob

I added sound effects to android game after I set up the rewarded advertises with admob on Unity. Here is my script for rewarded ads:

```
string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-5920324855307233/4458481507";
RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideo = null;

void Start () {
    managerScript = gameObject.GetComponent<GameManager>();
    isCalled = false;
    rewardBasedVideo = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;
}

public void adButton(){
    isCalled = true;
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded += HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;
    rewardBasedVideo.LoadAd(request, adUnitId);
}

void Update(){
    if(isCalled == true){
        adButton();
        showAd();
    }
}

public void showAd(){
    if (rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded()){
        rewardBasedVideo.Show();
    }
}

public void HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded(object sender, Reward args){
    isCalled = false;
    managerScript.revival();
    managerScript.Loading.SetActive(false);
    rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded -= HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;
}
```

Here is my script for sound effects (sound script):

```
public AudioClip Death;
public static bool toggled;
public static Sounds Instance;

public void DeathSound(){
    if(toggled == true){
    GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(Death);
  }
}

public void SoundToggle(){
if(toggled == false){
        toggled = true;
}else if(toggled == true){
        toggled = false;
    }
}
```

Finally how I call for a sound in another script:

```
Sounds sound;
GameObject soundManager;

public void Start(){
    soundManager = GameObject.Find("Sound Manager");
    sound = soundManager.GetComponent<Sounds>();
}

public void Death(){
    sound.DeathSound();
}
```

The problem is for some reason when the boolean "toggled" is true in the Sound script, the HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded method does not occur after the rewarded video advertise finishes. When sound is not toggled the method is called after the advertise and works fine. How is the sound effects being on affecting the method that happens after an advertise finishes? This problem is bothering me. Can someone help?

**Update:**
I tried disabling sound before the ad is loaded and then re enabling it after the ad. The problem still happens. Im not 100% certain but maybe the toggle bool has some effect, but I dont know how.

Comment: This is strange. Can you try making toggled not being static ? Perhaps something in the scopes is being messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Either your code is not complete in the question or you made a mistake because `GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(Death)` is not being called anywhere in the script. You are calling `DeathSound()` from `Death()` but nothing is calling `Death()` to call `DeathSound()` which actually plays the sound. Take a closer look at your code. Call `Death()` function from somewhere and your sound should play.

**EDIT**:

Did not read your question well first time.

Before you call the `showAd()` function, Check if the audio is playing then stop playing it. Also change your `Death` from `AudioClip` to `AudioSource`. If possible don't use `static` in your code. It will introduce lots of other problems. If you want to share variables between scenes, you can do that with the `PlayerPrefs` class instead of using static variables.

```
public void showAd(){

    if (Death.isPlaying)
    {
        Death.Stop();
    }

    if (rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded()){
        rewardBasedVideo.Show(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: how is this a answer? This should be a comment. Did  you even read his question completely? His problem is not with the sound not playing .

Comment: @UriPopov My bad. I read the thing wrong the first time and thought his audio is not playing. It happens sometimes.

Comment: I cant change the sound death to source as it is an actual sound file that needs to be played. I disabled all sounds before the advertise plays and then I re enabled it when it is done, It still does not work.